# Python: Strategy pattern with decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, strategy-pattern

I need to create an algorithm which is executed as a sequence of functions chosen at run-time, a bit like the strategy pattern. I want to avoid creating many single method classes (100+), but use simple functions, and assemble them using a decorator.

```
actions = []

def act(specific_fn):
    actions.append(specific_fn)
    return specific_fn


@act
def specific_fn1():
    print("specific_fn1")

@act
def specific_fn2():
    print("specific_fn2")

def execute_strategy():
    [f() for f in actions]
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I modify the decorator function `act` to take the list `actions` as a parameter, so that it adds the decorated function into the list?
2. How do I use `specific_fnX` defined in another file? Currently, I just import the file inside the calling function - but that seems odd. Any other options?

Also, any other ideas on implementing this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) is a pretty good tutorial on using decorators, both with and without arguments.  Others may know of others.

The trick is to remember that a decorator is a function call, but when applied to a function definition, it magically replaces the function with the returned result.  If you want `@my_decorator(my_list)` to be a decorator, then `my_decorator(my_list)` must either return a function or an object with a `__call__` method, and that function is then called on called on `specific_fn1`.

So yes, you need a function that returns a function that returns a function.  Looking at some examples in a tutorial will make this clearer.

As to your second question, you can just call `my_decorator(my_list)(specific_fn1)` without using a decorator, and then ignorning the result.